# Check if a line contains a sentence and generate error if next line contain other sentence

Tags: robotframework

I am new to using this framework.

I have a log file that may contain errors.

However, if a line contains the keyword "ERROR" then the following line the sentence "No provisioning file found", the error should not make the test fail, example :

```
...
2021-06-03 07:51:22,487|ERROR|http-listener-1
Message : No provisioning file found
...
```

Here we have an ERROR but followed by "Message : No provisioning file found" on the next line so it should not make the Test fail.

I wrote this:

```
Checking errors in logs

|{logs}=|Get File|${path}
|@{logLines}=|Split to lines|${logs}
||:FOR|${line}|IN|@{logLines}
      ?????
||END
```

But I don't know how to do the body of the loop because I have to go through the lines in pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to split and loop it over, you can directly check for substring from main string.

Define a variable with substring and check if main string (logs) contains your substring. key point is to put `\\n` in your substring variable, like i have put in my example, which would match across next line.  like below example:

```
*** Setting ***
Library     OperatingSystem

*** Variables ***
${str1}        "|ERROR|http-listener-1\\nMessage : No provisioning file found"


*** Test Cases ***
logs check
    ${logs}=    Get File    ${Path}
    log to console     ${logs}
    ${contains}=  Evaluate   ${str1} in """${logs}"""
    should be True    ${contains}
```

EDIT:As per your comment, you can check for regular expression also, using `Should match regexp`. like below:

```
*** Setting ***
Library     OperatingSystem

*** Variables ***
${reg1}        "|ERROR|*\\nMessage : No provisioning file found"

*** Test Cases ***
Logs Check
    ${logs}=    Get File    ${Path}
    log to console     ${logs}
    Should match regexp  ${reg1}  """${logs}"""
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

But there can be different characters between |ERROR| and Message : No provisioning file found

How can I specify a pattern like

"|ERROR|*\\nMessage : No provisioning file found"

Comment: @alexis yes, you can use `Should match regexp`, see my edited answer.

Comment: I have the error : Checking error :  bad escape \g at position 330 (line 2, column 156), do you have an idea?

Comment: from single line, i can't say anything, but the code i shared in edited part worked for me... is this error is coming from my code ? if not may be a different issue... another question :)